# How to retrieve nested object from cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data-jpa

I am Implementing an eCommerce application using spring boot. I am storing complex objects in the Cassandra database. Input object has the order Id and List of Product Information.

Product Information has a device name and serialNumber.

I want to retrieve data using serialNumber, serialNumber available under the list of product_details column.

Please suggest to me how to get an object in Cassandra DB.

Example Data in Cassandra DB:

```
id                                   | user_id                              | order_id | product_details
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------
     44c263b8 | ff3e2660 |      123 | [{"deviceName":"Smart Blub1","qty":"2","serialNo":"4444 "},{"deviceName":"Smart Plug1","qty":"1","serialNo":"654"}]
     08ed87f0 |       21 | [{"deviceName":"Smart Blub","qty":"2","serialNo":"333"},{"deviceName":"Smart Plug","qty":"1","serialNo":"123"}]
```

Output Example: If I pass product_details serialNo = 4444, The output result should be

```
  44c263b8 | ff3e2660 |      123 | [{"deviceName":"Smart Blub1","qty":"2","serialNo":"4444 "}]
```

Comment: you need to build your tables around your queries - in this case you need to redesign your table so you can search by serialNo...

Comment: @AlexOtt my input has list of items so I designed like that. Please give me some example so that I can redesign

Comment: In Cassandra, table design is built around queries, not queries around table structure